# Selective compilation: tag system exists in Latex?

Tags: compiling

I am trying to compile a document of talks I have texed. Currently I am putting each talk in a section, put them in a separate file, and include all of them in a main document. Is it possible for me to "tag" each section so that I can compile a document that shows only talks with a specific tag easily? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [LaTeX tag for making a comment appear or disappear in PDF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3023/5764) Use the [`comment` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment) for starters...