# How to set a newenvironment to skip words by flag?

Tags: environments, conditionals, comments

I want to create a environment to include some words, but hide it when a flag is set up. However, I cannot put `\begin{comment} \end{comment}` into `\newenvironment` for some reason.
How should I do this?

```
\newenvironment{FlagText}{\if\mycmd1 \begin{comment} \fi}%
{\if\mycmd1 \end{comment}\fi}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Do any of the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3023/15925 help?

Answer (score 3):

since you want only a word or so omitted, i think an ordinary command is better than an environment.  here's one possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifmycmd
\newcommand{\FlagText}[1]{%
  \ifhmode\unskip\fi
  \ifmycmd \else \space #1\fi
  }

\begin{document}

Here is some text \FlagText{with some words} to be ignored.

\FlagText{Start} a new paragraph with the first word flagged.

\mycmdtrue

Here is some text \FlagText{with some words} to be ignored.

\FlagText{Start} a new paragraph with the first word flagged.

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

the `\unskip` avoids possible messed-up spacing, and it is applied before
the omission so that a space is not left unintentionally at the end of
a line when the first word on the next line is what is omitted.

A perhaps better implementation using `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` (the usual LaTeX way of making commands “transparent”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifmycmd

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\FlagText}[1]{%
  \ifmycmd
    \@bsphack\expandafter\@esphack
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is some text \FlagText{with some words} to be ignored.

\FlagText{Start} a new paragraph with the first word flagged.

\mycmdtrue

Here is some text \FlagText{with some words} to be ignored.

\FlagText{Start} a new paragraph with the first word flagged.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` are better.

Comment: @egreg -- you're undoubtedly right, so feel free to modify.  (i'm i bit scared by the report that those definitions are changing in latex2015.)